# Php get image name in a link

Tags: php

i am using a script, to get the first image, inside a post.

Here is the script.

```
$first_img = '';
                $my1content = $row['post_content'];
                $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $my1content, $matches); 
                $first_img = $matches [1] [0];
                if(empty($first_img)){ //Defines a default image
                $first_img = "/img/default.png";
                }
```

This script echo the full image link, for example:
http://mywebsite.com/images/thisistheimage.jpg

is possible to divide the image link , image name , and image extenction
so i need to get 3 results

the link, example:http://mywebsite.com/images/
the image name, example: thisistheimage
the image extenction, example: .jpg

Please let me know if its all clear, thanks for reading.

Comment: Don't use Regex to parse HTML.

Comment: your regex is incorrect. multiple imgs on a single like are going to get sucked into a single result. NEVER use regexs for handling html unless you know EXACTLY what you're doing. use DOM instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
  $image_name       = pathinfo( $first_img, PATHINFO_FILENAME );
  $image_extension  = pathinfo( $first_img, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
  $image_with_extension = basename( $first_img );
  $image_directory      = dirname( $first_img );
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in function `pathinfo()` to parse the `src` for what you want.

```
$path_parts = pathinfo('/img/default.png');

echo $path_parts['dirname'], "\n";         // /img
echo $path_parts['basename'], "\n";        // default.png
echo $path_parts['extension'], "\n";       // .png
echo $path_parts['filename'], "\n";        //  default
```

The PHP reference is [here](http://nz1.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the built-in PHP function [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php). Looks like just what you need.

Comment: is posible to adapt it with my script please?

Comment: Mike W's answer above is more descriptive if you need more detail.